Memory card size limited by camera?
Nikon D7100 shows 128GB memory card is FULL, but when I looked at the data on a computer, it was only half full. Does th D7100 o/s have a card size limit?

Did you format the card in the camera? D7100 support up to 128GB cards.

@RomeoNinov DPreview and other sources mention SDXC cards, and these cards are up to 2TB. 128GB would be a very odd limit, cold be a confusion with 2x64GB cards total in the camera.

Can your computer report the filesystem type of your card? It should be exFAT, not FAT16 or FAT32.

Please note that before you try formatting the card in camera, be sure to copy and back up all of the data on the card to another storage medium (such as your computer's hard drive) because formatting will erase all data saved on the card!

Yes, there's a size limit. The D7100 user manual, page 347 states 64 GB as the maximum SDXC card size supported. The D7100 came out in 2013. So, while it can support SD, SDHC, and SDXC cards, it's not capable of doing the full range of possible SDXC memory addressing.
